# Trouble when creating Replica Set

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, helm, kubectl, mongodb

I want to convert a Standalone to a Replica Set for my MongoDb instance. I'm using Terraform and Helm and I manage K8s with my provider (Scaleway). The Helm file I'm using is : https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/mongodb

I can create 2 replicas and one arbiter, but they shut down until a short moment, in my terminal they seems to be in a loop.
I've got some error messages which are :

> readiness probe fail.

I'm new at Devops.

Here is my Terraform config :

```
resource "helm_release" "mongodb" {
  depends_on = [kubernetes_secret.tls_mongo]
  name       = "mongodb"
  repository = "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
  chart      = "mongodb"
  version    = "11.1.0" 
  namespace = "mongo"
  set {
    name  = "image.tag"
    value = "4.2"
  }
  set {
    name  = "auth.rootUser"
    value = var.mongo_username
  }
  set {
    name  = "auth.rootPassword"
    value = var.mongo_password
  }
  set {
    name  = "persistence.size"
    value = "10Gi"
  }
  set {
    name = "architecture"
    value = "replicaset" # standalone or replicaset
  }
  set {
    name = "auth.replicaSetKey"
    value = var.MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY
  }
}
```

Here are the status of my pods : The first pict is when they 're running and everything is fine. The other pict of the pods status is when everything is driving me crazy.

[image]

[image]

Can someone help me?

@enceladus2022

Logs of the events after this command

`kubectl describe pod mongodb-arbiter-0`

[image]

Comment: Can you share output of ```
kubectl describe pod mongodb-arbiter-0
``` Mainly interessting are events at the end if possible within timeframe when you start the deployment until it crashes.